# discrete cosine transform 8x8 block

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

to perform discrete cosine transform, an image must be divided into 8x8 blocks. But what about the image that have a size of, say, 35x25
then the result is

> 8x8 8x8 8x8 8x8 3x8
>
> 8x8 8x8 8x8 8x8 3x8
>
> 8x8 8x8 8x8 8x8 3x8
>
> 8x1 8x1 8x1 8x1 3x1

what should I do with a block of 3x8, 8x1 and 3x1?

I want to ask again, for RGB image each color component (R,G, and B)can directly perform DCT or should be converted to colorspace YcbCr before

Comment: "to perform discrete cosine transform, an image must be divided into 8x8 blocks." - That is not true.

Answer (score 2):

I think you refer to an application of the DCT (JPEG) where 8x8 blocks are somewhat of a compromise between artifacts and compression performance.
DCT by itself is not limited to 8x8 blocks.

You normally fill missing rows and columns with similar values (eg mirror the image) or if you can afford to lose some information cut away some rows/columns to get rid of incomplete blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. ya, I want to perform DCT to embed a message into frequeny matrix (steganography) and  this method suggested image should be divided into 8x8 blocks.
I want to ask again, for RGB image each color component can directly perform DCT or should be converted to colorspace YcbCr before